# Отправка формы клавишей enter

Tags: javascript, html

сама форма

```
<form action="index.php" name="searchform" method=get>
    <input type="text" id="auto1" name="searchstring" size="20" value="{$searchstring|default:""}">
</form>
```

отправка формы

```
<a id="aaa" onClick="First();" href="">отправить</a>
```

функция

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function First () {
    var url = 'index.php?searchstring=' + title;
    aaa.href =  url;
    }
</script>
```

Как по нажатию на клавишу enter её отправить? а если адаптировать эту функцию под button, то будет отправляться эта форма по клавише?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function submitForm() {
  alert('before submit');
  document.getElementById('frm').submit();
}

document.getElementById('auto1').onkeypress = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    submitForm();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" name="searchform" method="get" id="frm">
  <input type="text" id="auto1" name="searchstring" size="20" value="{$searchstring|default:" "}">
</form>

<a onclick="submitForm()" href="javascript://">отправить</a>
```

Comment: что-то не отправляется...точнее не реагирует

Comment: @sbaikov Вы нажали Enter, когда фокус был на input?

Comment: да, курсор был на input

Comment: @sbaikov JavaScript был ниже input'a?

Comment: да, пробовал и выше и ниже поставить

Comment: @sbaikov попробуйте сейчас, я изменил ответ

Comment: теперь перестал работать даже клик)

Comment: @sbaikov я добавил alert для теста, работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48487/discussion-between---and-sbaikov).

Answer (score 1):

Добавить кнопку `<input type="submit">` или `<button type="submit"></button>` **МОЖНО СКРЫТУЮ**

```
<form action="index.php" name="searchform" method=get>
    <input type="text" id="auto1" name="searchstring" size="20" value="{$searchstring|default:""}">
<input type="submit" style='display: none;'>
</form>
```